# What is the meaning of assigning to return value of getter taking this pointer by value?

Tags: c++, this, getter, return-by-reference, return-by-value

This doubt came to me when I jumped on an existing code and mistakenly used a getter to set a property,

```cpp
obj.getProp() = otherProp;
```

instead of calling the setter,

```cpp
obj.setProp(otherProp);
```

I did not realize the mistake because there was no error at compilation or runtime; the assignment resulted in a no-op.

So I came up with the following example, which outputs `337`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int x = 0;
    A(int x) : x(x) {}
    A(A& a) : x(a.x) {}
    void operator=(A const& other) { x = other.x; }
};

struct B {
    A a{3};
    int x{3};
    A  getAbyVal() { return a; }
    A& getAbyRef() { return a; }
    int getXbyVal() { return x; }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    std::cout << b.a.x;   // this and the other two cout print what I expect, but...
    b.getAbyVal() = A{7}; // ... I expected this to fail at compilation time in the first place...
    //b.getXbyVal() = 3;  // ... just like this fails.
    std::cout << b.a.x;
    b.getAbyRef() = A{7};
    std::cout << b.a.x;

}
```

So my question is two folds:

- what in `b.getAbyVal() = A{7};` is different from `b.getXbyVal() = 3;` so that the former compiles and the latter doesn't (beside the fact that the types are `A` and `int`)?
- changing `void operator=(A const& other) { x = other.x; }` to `void operator=(A const& other) & { x = other.x; }` makes `b.getAbyVal() = A{7};` fail to compile. Why is this the case?

Comment: In `A& getAbyRef()` the `&` belongs to the return type `A&`. In `void operator=(A const& other) &` it acts as a reference qualifier and it not associated with the return type. Those two uses of `&` are not comparable.

Comment: `void operator=` usually the return type is a reference to the object.  Personally, I prefer returning `void` for assignment like you have here, but it's not idiomatic C++.  If your team is onboard with returning `void`, all is good.

Comment: @Eljay, no my team is not onboard, but I thought returning `void` would help me (and the readers of the question) making less cofusion between the types of explicit arguments, the implicit argument `this`, and the returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what in b.getAbyVal() = A{7}; is different from b.getXbyVal() = 3; so
> that the former compiles and the latter doesn't (beside the fact that
> the types are A and int)?

Surprisingly, the difference in types is exactly what makes one compile correctly, and other to fail.

`A` has an assignment operator defined for it, so compiler dutifully invokes it on the return value (only to discard the whole object later). But the code you wrote supports this. From the compiler view, some other interesting things might have happened in your assignment operator, despite the fact that the object will be eradicated (*side effects* in formal parlance).

With `int` as a return value, compiler **knows** there are no side effects of assigning value to int, so assigning any value to object which is to be eradicated immediately does not make any sense.

Comment: Accepted this because it clarifies that assigning to an rvalue object is not erroneous because the assignment happens via the `operator=` function, which could have side effects beside (possibly, but not necessarily) assigning something to the `*this` operand which will be deleted right after the call.

Answer (score 1):

> what in `b.getAbyVal() = A{7};` is different from `b.getXbyVal() = 3;` so that the former compiles and the latter doesn't (beside the fact that the types are `A` and `int`)?

The difference is precisely that one functions returns a class type, and the other function returns a POD type. A temporary `int`, for example can't be assigned to:

```
42 = x; // error
```

so similarly the language disallows assigning to a temporary `int` returned from a function as well. This is not the default behavior for user-defined class types so assigning to a temporary `A` compiles:

```
A{} = x; // ok
```

---

> changing `void operator=(A const& other) { x = other.x; }` to `void operator=(A const& other) & { x = other.x; }` makes `b.getAbyVal() = A{7};` fail to compile. Why is this the case?

Adding a `&` at the end of is called a ref-qualifier, and allows a user-defined class to have the same semantics as a POD type when it comes to assigning to a temporary. Adding a `&` at the end of `operator=` constrains it to only be used on an l-value (basically, a named variable, or a reference returned from a function).

```
A{} = x;  // now error
A a;
a = x;    // still ok
```

Comment: On a surface, `42` is different from return value of a function. I question the validity of this comparison for the purpose of the question.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the temporary as a comparison that might make sense to the OP. It seems reasonable enough to address this question.